# entityManagerEntity proplem in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

everyone, I am having this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at theo.tziomakas.entities.EntitiesApplication.main(EntitiesApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>theo.tziomakas</groupId>
<artifactId>entities</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>entities</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Entities</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--WebJars-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--encryption lib-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180725.0427</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildVersionProperty(PropertyFactory.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
... 33 common frames omitted
```

I search other people's solutions but didn't work. I would prefer to have a an answer to my problem rather than endless links.

Comment: For starters remove the jaxb dependency (the one you included is for java 10 and jaxb is still part of the JDK with java 8).

Comment: @M. Deinum . I did that but still get that funny exception. What else should I try?

Comment: Could you please share the whole exception? What configuration do you have for Spring atm?

Comment: @galovics. Please check my updated log. I am using Spring 2.0.4 if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Aren't you using `@Version` in one of your entities with a String attribute?

Comment: @galovics. Oh no. I was using String for the version variable and not Integer! I works now.

Comment: @ galovics. Spot on. Well done. thanks.

Comment: So report a bug on your JPA provider for not giving an error message that says that ... instead of `Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister` (which means what???)

Comment: @BillyFrost if you check the end of the `pom.xml`, the message was there but copied to the wrong place.

Comment: I'd still expect "user friendly software" to do a better job of error reporting than just checking out ClassCastException and expecting people to work it out. What about `Class xxx has a version field "version" of type yyy but this is not supported. Should be of type zzz`? How hard is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use versioning with a `String` type attribute in one of your entities. Change it to `int` or something else which is supported by default for versioning and it will work.